How do I push the result on stack in a subroutine?
org 0x0100      
jmp start  

; Declare variables
input1: db 0  
input2: db 7  
input3: db 9  
input4: db 1  
message1: db 'The value of AX, BX and CX is: '
length: dw 31

start:
    ; Push output variables with random values
    push 3       ; Random value 1
    push 5       ; Random value 2
    push 7       ; Random value 3

    call my_subroutine

    ; Retrieve output variables
    pop cx       ; Retrieve output into CX
    pop bx       ; Retrieve output into BX
    pop ax       ; Retrieve output into AX

    ;Display the output values
    call display
    
    ; Exit program
    mov ax, 0x4c00
    int 0x21

my_subroutine:
    ; Save registers
    push ax
    push bx
    push si
    push di
    push cx

    ; Local variables (initialized with random values)
    local1: dw 1
    local2: dw 2
    local3: dw 3
    local4: dw 4
    local5: dw 5

    ; Example operations (just random logic for demonstration)
    mov ax, [input1] ; Load first input
    add ax, [local1] ; Add local variable
    mov bx, [input2] ; Load second input
    sub bx, [local2] ; Subtract local variable

    ; Push results
    ;push ax          ; Push first output (AX)
    ;push bx          ; Push second output (BX)
    ;mov cx, word [input3]      
    ;push cx          ; Push third output (local variable)

    ; Restore registers
    pop cx           ; Pop last pushed value into CX
    pop bx           ; Restore BX
    pop ax           ; Restore AX
    pop di           ; Restore DI
    pop si           ; Restore SI
    ret              ; Return to the caller

cls:

  push es
  push ax
  push di

  mov ax, 0xB800
  mov es, ax
  mov di, 0

 allSpace:

 mov word [es:di], 0x0720
 add di, 2
 cmp di, 4000
 jne allSpace

 pop di
 pop ax
 pop es

 ret

convert_num_to_string:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp 
    push es
    pusha
    mov ax, 0xb800
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, [bp+4]
    mov bx, 10
    mov cx, 0

 nextdigit: 
    mov dx, 0
    div bx
    add dl, 0x30
    push dx
    inc cx
    cmp ax, 0
    jnz nextdigit


    nextpos: 
    pop dx
    mov dh, 0x07
    mov [es:di], dx
    add di, 2
    loop nextpos

    popa
    pop es
    pop bp
    ret 2

display_message:
  push bp
  mov bp, sp
  push es
  push ax
  push bx
  push cx

  mov ax, 0xb800
  mov es, ax

  mov si, [bp+6]
  mov cx, [bp+4]
  mov ah, 0x07

  printAllChar:
  
  mov al, [si]
  mov [es:di], ax
  add di, 2
  add si, 1
  loop printAllChar

  pop cx
  pop bx
  pop ax
  pop es
  pop bp
  ret 4

display:  
    call cls
    mov di, 0                  
    push message1                  
    push word [length]
    call display_message
    
    mov di, 62 
    push ax           
    call convert_num_to_string

    mov di, 66
    push bx           
    call convert_num_to_string

    mov di, 70
    push cx           
    call convert_num_to_string


    ret




Main problem in my_subroutine:
In the subroutine above, when I push my result onto the stack, the control does not return to below call my_subroutine, but rather an infinite loop runs.
By the way, here is the question I am trying to solve:

You are required to write a subroutine in assembly language that:

Takes 4 input variables (which will be the digits from your roll number i.e 22F-3440 , 3440 are the 4 inputs).
Returns 3 output variables. These output variables are pushed (with random values) before the input variables in the main.
Creates 5 local variables inside the function. Initialized with random values from 1 to 10.
Uses the registers AX, BX, SI, DI, and CX to perform operations, but save and restore these registers before and after use to avoid
overwriting their original values.
The outputs must be popped into AX, BX, and CX after the subroutine returns.
Display these to the console.



ret works by popping a return address into IP, so extra pushes will un-balance the stack and change where your function returns.  Your assignment requires you to copy the args and return address farther down the stack to make room for the 3 outputs.  (This is very weird and inefficient, not a normal calling convention, but is a good learning exercise.)

local1: dw 1 puts your static variable in the middle of your code, where the CPU will fetch and decode it as machine code.  Don't do that.  Local variables means stack space which you reserve with push or sub sp, 5*2.

@PeterCordes i literally solved this issue 2 sec before seeing your comment but really appericiate your help thnx man

@PeterCordes but how do i push my result down the stack to make room for 3 outputs? a little help here.

One way to copy memory is push [bp+6] / push [bp+8] etc. after setting up BP as a frame pointer.  Or you could copy a block with rep movsw.

thnx a lot   really helped

If you control the function protocol you can also have the caller allocate stack space for the output parameters before calling the function. Then the function can just use this space without shuffling what's on the stack.

@ecm: Oh, I think that's actually what the assignment is implying with These output variables are pushed (with random values) before the input variables in the main. - I think they're saying main should do 3 pushes to reserve space for the output variables.  That's a lot more sane, and a bit easier to implement.

@ecm i didnt get what you are trying to say can you eloborate it ?

@Fatimasami As Peter Cordes said this is actually what your exercise intends. The pushes marked with the comments "Random value" make space on the stack. You should save and restore bp in your subfunction. After push bp use mov bp, sp and then address the reserved space on the stack using mov word [bp + x], y where you have to calculate x to access the correct stack slots.

can you give me the modified code for the subroutine if it is possible  @ecm
and i made the follwing changes in my code are they accrding to the question requirments?
my_subroutine:
; Savig registers
jmp cont1
; Local variables (initialized with random values)
cont1:
; Load input variables into registers for operations
loading input variables
; pushing result on stack
mov [bp + 4], cx
mov [bp + 6], bx
mov [bp + 8], ax
; Restore registers
; restoring registers
ret              ; Return to the caller


; Local variables (initialized with random values)
local1: dw 1
local2: dw 2
local3: dw 3
local4: dw 4
local5: dw 5


These are not local variables! They're just as global as those other variables that you've declared (input, message, length). They only seem local because their name says so and because you've written them inside the my_subroutine subroutine. In many assemblers you could at least make these variables 'accessible local-only', by prepending their names with a dot: .local1: dw 1. But this is still not ideal because they will continue to occupy their memory for as long as your program runs.
Additionally because of their emplacement in the execution path of your program, the cpu will execute these data bytes with possible disastrous results. In your main you knew that you had to jump around the data declarations with that jmp start. So, you could have used something similar here.
Anyway, for your task the best solution is to place the local variables on the stack. See the code example below.

; Save registers
push ax
push bx
push si
push di
push cx

...

; Restore registers
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax
pop di
pop si
ret


You must restore the registers in the reverse order to how you pushed them before. Except for CX, this is not the case here!


Returns 3 output variables. These output variables are pushed (with random values) before the input variables in the main.


This is an important sentence and my take on it, is that a total of 7 values get pushed on the stack prior to calling the subroutine. Since unlike for the local variables, no limit was placed on the random values, you could save a few bytes and just push whatever (random) value there happens to be in the AX, BX, and CX registers. Alternatively, just consider the stack memory is already filled with such 'random' values, and thus a mere sub sp, 6 will reserve the space for those 3 outputs:
  ; Push output variables with random values
  push cx      ; (1)                 alternative:   sub sp, 6    ; (1)(2)(3)
  push bx      ; (2)
  push ax      ; (3)
  ; Push input variables with digits from roll number
  push 1       ; 4th digit
  push 9       ; 3rd digit
  push 7       ; 2nd digit
  push 0       ; 1st digit
  call my_subroutine
  pop  ax      ; (3)
  pop  bx      ; (2)
  pop  cx      ; (1)

Stack layout once we're inside the subroutine:
1  2  3  4  5  CX DI SI BX AX BP RET 0  7  9  1  ?  ?  ?
^  ^                          ^      ^  ^        ^  ^  ^
|  [bp-18]                    [bp]   |  [bp+6]   |  |  [bp+16]
[bp-20]                              [bp+4]      |  [bp+14]
                                                 [bp+12]

my_subroutine:
  push bp
  mov  bp, sp
  push ax      ; Save registers
  push bx
  push si
  push di
  push cx
  push 5       ; Local variables (initialized with random values)
  push 4
  push 3
  push 2
  push 1

  ; Example operations (just random logic for demonstration)
  mov  ax, [bp+4]    ; Load first input
  add  ax, [bp-20]   ; Add local variable
  mov  bx, [bp+6]    ; Load second input
  sub  bx, [bp-18]   ; Subtract local variable
  ...


  mov  [bp+12], ax   ; "Push" results
  mov  [bp+14], bx
  mov  [bp+16], cx
  add  sp, 10        ; Release local variables
  pop  cx            ; Restore registers
  pop  di
  pop  si
  pop  bx
  pop  ax
  pop  bp
  ret  8             ; Remove the 4 inputs


display_message currently forgets to preserve SI and DI, but needlessly preserves BX. Also it's a bit strange to see DI as a register-input to this routine together with a couple of stack-inputs. I think 3 stack-inputs OR 3 register-inputs would be nicer...

You forgot to mention just how bad a correctness problem it is to put static variables inside the machine-code for a function, where they'll be decoded as machine-code and executed. Segmentation fault when using DB (define byte) inside a function , or for 16-bit code Assembly (x86):  db 'string',0 does not get executed unless there's a jump instruction

Agreed that the assignment is saying main should do 3 "dummy" pushes to reserve space for outputs.  That could be sub sp, 6 or 3x push ax or 3x push si.  Pushing 3 different registers in the opposite order from how you're later going to pop them seems less simple.

@Sep Roland your answer seems to be right although i havnt run it on afd debugger
but thnx alot for this detailed explaination

@Sep Roland  i have gone through the explaination of Sep Roland and implemented it but there was an infinte loop running. i have fixed it and solved the question but only one confusion is still there i have edited my question for it. kindlly can you guys review my updated question. will appreciate a lot

@ecm kindly go through my updated question

@PeterCordes kindly go through my updated question

@Fatimasami: That's a new question you need to ask separately.  Your edit invalidates most of this answer about how to interpret the part of the assignment saying to push space for outputs before pushing the inputs, since your question now answers itself for that part.  I've rolled back your edit.  You can open the edit history and click "source" for the previous revision if you want to copy/paste the markdown from there as the basis for a new question.

@Fatimasami: But actually the new question you're asking has a pretty simple answer: all functions use the same stack, but different parts of it if one is calling another.  If a parent function calls the first function and pops its results, that deallocates that stack memory.  If it then calls the second function, the same stack memory gets reused.  It's never in use for both functions at once.  It will have to save the first or second results somewhere other than AX/CX/DX if it wants to have both available at once.  Other regs, or in other space the caller allocated.

@PeterCordes do i have to pop both results in main and display them seperatly?

@Fatimasami: Technically no; if you call an output function that takes args on the stack, you could just call it since the values you want to pass are already on the stack, where your earlier function left them.  But yes, anything you want your program to output, you have to write code that does so.  You don't need to have all 6 return values "live" at the same time, after displaying the first 3 your program can forget about them.  (Not save them anywhere, letting the stack memory and registers get overwritten by the calling the second function).  Just like how you normally reuse registers.
